# Parse file to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = open("state_towns.txt")
    for line in data:
        print(line)
```

returns the following list:

```
Colorado[edit]

Alamosa (Adams State College)[2]

Boulder (University of Colorado at Boulder)[12]

Durango (Fort Lewis College)[2]

Connecticut[edit]

Fairfield (Fairfield University, Sacred Heart University)

Middletown (Wesleyan University)

New Britain (Central Connecticut State University)
```

I want to return a dataframe with two columns, state and region, that would look like this:

```
    State        Town
0   Colorado     Alamosa
1   Colorado     Boulder
2   Colorado     Durango 
3   Connecticut  Fairfield
4   Connecticut  Middletown
5   Connecticut  New Britain
```

How do i split the list so that any line that contains '[edit]' will be added to the state column?

Also how to I delete all the text in the brackets from the town entries?

thanks

Comment: This is not a simple convert a list to a dataframe question, this is a question on how to parse that particular file format into a dataframe.

Comment: Also how does the data of Auburn, Florence and Jacksonville for Colorado come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {"state":[], "town":[]} #dictionary to hold the data
state = "" #placeholder state var
town = "" #placeholder town var

data = open("state_towns.txt")
    for line in data:
        if "[edit]" in line:
            state = line.replace("[edit]","") #set the state var if it has edit
        else:
            town = line.split()[0] #remove the extra town line info
        if state != "" and town != "": # if both vars are filled add to dictionary
            d["state"].append(state)
            d["town"].append(town)


import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

This is pretty wack but it does the job.

placeholder state, placeholder town which get defined in the loop. If both are defined add them to a dictionary, when done convert the dictionary into a data frame.